Any subspace $V\subset T_xM$ is the tangent space of a minimal submanifold.
The following appears to be a standard fact:

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $x\in M$ and $V\subset T_xM$ a subvectorspace. Then there is a minimal submanifold (not necessarily closed) $B$ of $M$ so that $x\in B$ and $T_xB=V$.

One can prove it by applying the Banach space implicit function theorem to the minimal graph equation, basically the same proof that any $v\in T_xM$ is the gradient of a harmonic function defined in a neighbourhood of $x$.
But I cannot find a reference for this fact, and would much prefer a reference than to write out the details of the proof.

Question. Where can one find a proof of the above statement?


If this is for a article in a research journal, your one sentence sketch of the proof is enough.
